# Storing marker locations in list

Tags: android, google-maps, android-listview, google-maps-markers, listadapter

I am adding marker on google map using onmapclicklistener and deleting it the same way. What I want is that when the user adds a marker, it's location and radius be saved in a list(radius is taken from user in dialog fragment) , and when user deletes marker, it should be deleted from list as well. What approach should I use.
My code is
     public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements View.OnClickListener,MapDropdown.DialogListener {

```
public static final String mapLongitude="longitude";
public static final String mapLatitude="latitude";
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
Button displayareas;
Switch deleteareas;
private boolean del = false;


private GoogleMap newmap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    displayareas = (Button) findViewById(R.id.display);
    displayareas.setOnClickListener(this);
    deleteareas = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.delete);
    deleteareas.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                     boolean isChecked) {

            if (isChecked) {
                del = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Deleting enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                del = false;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Deleting disabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });
    Log.d("Map","MapCreated");
    setUpMapIfNeeded();

}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.display) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AllAreas.class);

        startActivity(intent);
    }

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //setUpMapIfNeeded();
}


private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (newmap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        newmap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (newmap != null) {
            setUpMap();
            Log.d("MAPS","Map working");


        }
        else Log.d("MAPS","not working");

    }
}


private void setUpMap() {

    newmap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker").snippet("Snippet"));

    // Enable MyLocation Layer of Google Map
    newmap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    // Get LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // Create a criteria object to retrieve provider
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    // Get the name of the best provider
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    // Get Current Location
    Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    // set map type
    newmap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    // Get latitude of the current location
    double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();

    // Get longitude of the current location
    double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

    // Create a LatLng object for the current location
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    // Show the current location in Google Map
    newmap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

    // Zoom in the Google Map
    newmap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20));
    newmap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("My location"));

    Log.d("LATITUDE",String.valueOf(latitude));
    Log.d("LONGITUDE",String.valueOf(longitude));
    GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener listener = new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
            if(del == false){

           MapDropdown dFragment = new MapDropdown();
            // Show DialogFragment
            dFragment.show(fm, "Dialog Fragment");}
            else if(del == true){
                marker.remove();
            }
            return true;


        }

    };

    newmap.setOnMarkerClickListener(listener);

    newmap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

            // Creating a marker
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

            // Setting the position for the marker
            markerOptions.position(latLng);

            // Setting the title for the marker.
            // This will be displayed on taping the marker
            markerOptions.title(latLng.latitude + " : " + latLng.longitude);


            // Animating to the touched position
            newmap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

            // Placing a marker on the touched position
            Marker mmarker = newmap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            Log.d("ADDED LATITUDE",String.valueOf(latLng.latitude));
            Log.d("ADDED LONGITUDE",String.valueOf(latLng.longitude));

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Block area updated",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();





        }
    });

}
@Override
public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog){
    Log.d("Button","positive");

}
@Override
public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog){
Log.d("Button","negative");

  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna retrieve the list when your app reopen. You can use the `location file system` to store the list.

First you if you want to save both `location` and `radius`, you can create a object named `UserLocation` for that.

Second create a `Arraylist` named `items` for that object when the user create a marker, add that object to the `Arraylist`. and then save the `Arraylist` by using following method:

```
private void writeItems() {
        File fileDir = getFilesDir();
        File locationFile = new File(fileDir, "locations.txt");
        try {
            FileUtils.writeLines(locationFile, items);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Finally, you can retrieve the data by using this:

```
private void readItems() {
        File filesDir = getFilesDir();
        File locationFile = new File(filesDir, "locations.txt");
        try {
            items = new ArrayList<UserLocation>(FileUtils.readLines(locationFile));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            items = new ArrayList<locationFile>();
        }
    }
```